# Vertically Align Text Next To Image With CSS Not Working

Tags: html, css

Alright so I have looked a bunch of other stack overflow questions like this and nothing has seemed to work. I don't know why its not working must be something silly that im not catching.

My CSS

```
.how-right {
}
.how-right img {
    float:right;
    margin-left:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.how-left {
}
```

My HTML

```
<!-- Number 1 -->
<div style="height:259px;" class="how-right">
    <img src="img/how-it-works/num-1.PNG" width="267px" height="259px">
    <span> has a simple system to get you in shape in just 6 weeks.  And it's so easy to follow, even people who have never exercised before can do it.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
span {
    height: 259px;            
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

​
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rVTcv/)

Also, [more options](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/) for vertically centering multi-lined text.

Comment: I was giving the same answer. +1 for this

Comment: I just realized that my answer is practically the same thing. +1.

Answer (score 1):

You should be vertically-aligning the `span` tag. You should use the CSS tables: `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. These will not make the elements into actual tables, but it will simply allow `vertical-align` to be used properly (it basically treats everything as inline, rather than block).

Apply `display:table` to the parent element (`how-right`, in your case). Apply `display:table-cell` to the actual `span` tag.

Here's the CSS:

```
.how-right img {
    float:right;
    margin-left:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
span {
    height: 259px;            
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle so you can see the final result: http://jsfiddle.net/zdZYY/